# elasticsearch maintenance of index time synonyms - Reindexing

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I have huge list of synonyms which is subjected to updated once every day.
In order to reflect the updated synonyms I need to reindex my docuements.
I wanted suggestions on which is the best way to achieve this. Assuming synonyms are updated once every day.

PS: I am aware of search time synonyms vs index time synonyms, would still like to proceed with index time synonyms

Comment: How about having it in a file and reopening the index?

Comment: I do have synonyms in a file, for index time synonyms to work, reindexing is manditory